# Regular expression to remove substring with known start and end pattern, with multiple words in between

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the example substring I'm trying to remove:

> On Feb 4, 2018 11:00 PM,

Problem is it can appear multiple times in a string. I just want to remove it/replace with nothing eg. `''`.

You could do this a lazy way where you know the length of the pattern, substring it.

I have tried a regex like this:

`str.replaceAll(/^On*PM,$/g, '')`

Where the `^` and `$` indicate start end... I'm missing the space/multiple words.

The months/time are dynamic but not that many combinations.

Comment: for one, regex has different syntax to glob patterns, so `n*` means "zero or more n", the star is a quantifier, not something by itself.

Comment: Cheap attempt: `/On.*?PM,/` - note that the one from the answer is probably cheaper to execute, but that's often not too important.

Comment: Interesting guess you don't need the ^ and $, it does work. I will opt for the one below simply for thoroughness but thanks.

Comment: Also note, that the above eats similar things too, e.g. `"On that day, i wrote him a PM, and [...]"`. So the answer is more "clean". You should read a tutorial on regex, `^` and `$` are start and end of string, which isn't what you want, if it's a substring somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Yeah I think I misunderstood what start/end means eg. the entire sentence vs. what I'm searching for. About the variation, yeah that is a concern, in which case I can do a length check to be sure, but generally this pattern is rare in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/\bOn\s+(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sept?|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]),\s*\d{4}\s*(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s*[AP]M,/gi
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/IRBrnj/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  On                       'On'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jan                      'Jan'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Feb                      'Feb'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mar                      'Mar'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Apr                      'Apr'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    May                      'May'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jun                      'Jun'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jul                      'Jul'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Aug                      'Aug'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sep                      'Sep'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    t?                       't' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Oct                      'Oct'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Nov                      'Nov'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dec                      'Dec'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0?                       '0' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [12]                     any character of: '1', '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3                        '3'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [01]                     any character of: '0', '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0?                       '0' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-2]                    any character of: '0' to '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-5]?                   any character of: '0' to '5' (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [AP]                     any character of: 'A', 'P'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  M,                       'M,'
```

Or, simpler one if the strings you deal with are in good shape:

```js
/\bOn\s+\w+\s+\d{1,2},\s*\d{4}\s*\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s*[AP]M,/gi
```

See [this proof](https://regex101.com/r/IRBrnj/3).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  On                       'On'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [AP]                     any character of: 'A', 'P'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  M,                       'M,'
```

Comment: wow that is more intense than I expected, I guess it's not that simple to not care what's in between/just use the start-end caps -- not guaranteed to be coincidence though if just using On...PM,

Comment: @JacobDavidC.Cunningham I added another simpler variation that can help if your strings are in good shape.